# How do I close a sheet opened with golang lib excelize?

Tags: go

I followed the repo (https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize) tutorial to open a file:

```
f, err := excelize.OpenFile("./Book1.xlsx")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}enter code here
```

But i couldn't find  a tutorial about closing, something like:

```
defer f.Close()
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to close it.
Just open it, and save it if you need to.

`myFile, err := excelize.OpenFile("./Book1.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    return
}`

Then, do what you want.

Finally, just save it with the origin path :

`err = myFile.Save()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
}`

Or, an other path :

`err := myFile.SaveAs("./myFolder/Book2.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
}`